# Grant access to NAB programatically on iOS 7.0 Simulator

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-simulator, abaddressbook, xctest

Is it possible to grant access to the native address book (NAB) on iOS 7.0 Simulator programmatically? I am writing **xctest** Unit Tests that need **write access** to NAB. The unit tests are run on **iOS 7.0 Simulator** and are part of Continuous Integration process and doesn't involve any user interaction.

Currently unless the user grants access explicitly via the *“TestApp” Would like to Access Your Contacts* alert, access to NAB is denied.

Comment: iOS 8 version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30106320/476716

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the spirit of sharing I am going to answer my own question. Among other permissions, **Address Book** access permission is stored in `TCC.db` database that is located in `/Library/TCC/` in the iPhone Simulator folder.

```
e.g. /Users/useriko/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/[appGUID]/Library/TCC/TCC.db
```

Permissions are stored in the `access` table in TCC.db database. `access` table schema is:
[image: TCC.db schema]

The fields we are interested in are:

1. `service` - the permission type
2. `client`   - the app identifier
3. `allowed` - permission granted?

In order to grant **Access Book** permission, and appropriate record should be inserted into the `access` table (or updated if already exists). After the record was either inserted or updated the table should look like that:
[image: access table after update]

I've wrote the following method to update the TCC.db database.

```
#import <sqlite3.h>

- (void)grantAccessBookAccess {
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  // tccDbPath: /Users/useriko/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/FB8DF5E9-94B8-4CA9-A167-43AFE794B94E/Document

  NSString *tccDbPath = nil;
  tccDbPath = [[[[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                  stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]  // remove Document
                  stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]  // remove [appGUID]
                  stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]; // remove Applications

  // tccDbPath: /Users/useriko/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/

  tccDbPath = [[[tccDbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"]
                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TCC"]
                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TCC.db"];

  // tccDbPath: /Users/useriko/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Library/TCC/TCC.db

  sqlite3 *database;
  if(sqlite3_open([tccDbPath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Error while opening database. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    return;
  }

  NSString *updateSql = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO access (service, client, client_type, allowed, prompt_count) VALUES (\"kTCCServiceAddressBook\",\"com.your.app.id\",0,1,1);";

  int rc;
  char* errmsg;
  const char *sql = [updateSql UTF8String];
  rc = sqlite3_exec(database, sql, NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Error updating access table. %s", errmsg);
    sqlite3_free(errmsg);
  }

  sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Because of the obvious reasons, the target should be linked with **libsqlite3.dylib**.

**DO NOT** forget to change the app identifier (*com.your.app.id*) in the `updateSql` to your app identifier.

Comment: any ideas how to do it in swift3 ?

Comment: @Async Sorry. No idea.

Answer (score 1):

This Cocoapod works great for testing purposes: https://github.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks