# Manipulate app permissions on iOS 8 simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, xctest, ios-permissions

Same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24497022/476716), but for iOS 8.

While running xctests, how can I make sure permissions are granted/denied programmatically?

Is the same TCC.db used? If so, as there are no `$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/8.x` directories, where has it moved to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [username tbd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025345/476716), the TCC.db is still in use, but is now located at

`$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEID/data/Library/TCC/`

Schema of the "access" table is the same.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *dbPath = [paths firstObject];

for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
    dbPath = [dbPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
}

dbPath = [[[dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"]
           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TCC"]
          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TCC.db"];
```

Note though that TCC is only for Accounts access (contacts, mail, etc.) and not all permissions.